# Systems of Equations (Inconsistent)

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, analytic-geometry

> > Question: Consider the following system of three equations:
> >
> > $$2y+2z=9-2x$$
> >     $$x=12-3y-4z$$
> >     $$Ax+5y+6z=B$$
> >
> > Find values of A and B which makes the system of equations inconsistent and then give a geometric interpretation (sketch a diagram)

What I have attempted:

$$2y+2z=9-2x ⇔ 2x+2y+2z=9$$
 $$x=12-3y-4z ⇔ x+3y+4z=12$$
$$Ax+5y+6z=B$$

Using the first 2 equations to find y in terms of x
$$2x+2y+2z=9$$

$$x+3y+4z=12$$

To eliminate z multiply first equation by 2

$$4x+4y+4z=18$$

$$x+3y+4z=12$$

$$ 3x+y = 6  ⇔ \mathbf{y=6-3x}$$

To eliminate y multiply first equation by 3 and multiply second equation by 2

$$6x+6y+6z=27$$

$$2x+6y+8z=24$$

$$ 4x-2z=3 ⇔ \mathbf{z=2x-\frac{3}{2}}$$

Subbing in $\mathbf{y=6-3x}$ and $\mathbf{z=2x-\frac{3}{2}}$ into $$Ax+5y+6z=B$$

$$ Ax+5(6-3x) + 6(2x-\frac{3}{2}) = B $$

$$ Ax-3x+21 = B $$

$$ (A-3)x + 21 = B $$

To have a system inconsistent (x=0)

$$ (A-3) = 0 ⇔ A = 3 $$

$$ A = 3 $$
$$ B = 21 $$

(Please check If i am correct) and if so how would I make a geometric representation of this inconsistent system of equations?

I searched google and got this [image]

but I'm not too sure if it is correct.. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key point is to rewrite your system into a matrix form, then examine the determinant $D$ of your system. it is $D=2A-6$.

If $D$ is nonzero, there is a unique solution (your planes intersect into a single point).

If $D=0$, i.e. for $A=3$, look at your system. Assume that it has a solution $(x,y,z)$. Visibly, if you add the first 2 equations and substract the last one, you obtain $0=21-B$.

Either $B \neq 21$, no solution can exist, by contradiction.

Or $B=21$, in which case the third equation, being a consequence of the first 2 can be cancelled. You are left with two planes which intersect into a line representing an infinite number of solutions (this case, three planes intersecting along a common line, is not represented in your graphics)

Edit: As you are still in high school, in order to understand what is a determinant (a central concept/tool in mathematics) and how it can be used, I advise you to begin by http://www.mathnstuff.com/math/algebra/adeterm.htm which intrduces the two dimensional case. Then proceed to the article ("Applications" part) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer's_rule treating as well the completely similar 3 dimensional case, knowing that a $3 \times 3$ determinant can be computed by Sarrus' method https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus. This method is effective and gives a UNIQUE solution  if the determinant of the system is non zero (it is the common denominator). Said otherwise, exceptional cases can only happen when the system's determinant is zero.

Comment: Your values agree with mines... but my conclusion is not the same: if $B=21$, the system is consistent, i.e., possesses (at least) a solution (in fact many)

Comment: Then what would B equal?

Comment: Thus the cases of inconsistency are $A=3 and B \neq 21$.

Comment: Is it OK now ? The conclusion is that, for parametrized systems, a good policy is to look first to the determinant of the system.

Comment: I'm in high school so we don't use matrixs/determinant. I'm still confused , could you explain the 2 cases where B = 23 and B =/=23 so I could understand in elementary terms. :)

Comment: See the "Edit" part I have added to my answer. As you are in high school and visibly want to know more I encourage you to persist: you will see, Mathematics are VERY rewarding !